# Cantor’s diagonal proof revisited

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation, real-numbers

In his diagonal argument (although I believe he originally presented another proof to the same end) Cantor allows himself to manipulate the number he is checking for (as opposed to check for a fixed number such as $\pi$), and I wonder if that involves some meta-mathematical issues.

Let me similarly check whether a number I define is among the natural numbers. The number is $n+1$ and it is clear that $1$, $2$, $3,\ldots,\ n$ are not among these numbers. This “proves” that $n+1$ is not a natural number.

I have here, just like Cantor, a formula for a number, rather than a given number. What is the difference between our proofs?

It seems to me that the answer is that Cantor’s number (as opposed to mine) is being successively better bounded; the process of moving forward in his enumeration describes a converging series, such as we use to define the real numbers, using Cauchy limits. You don’t hear this added comment in the proof. Don’t you think it belongs to the proof?

Comment: I don't see what you mean by him manipulating the number he is checking for. The arguments shows that given any map from the naturals to the reals, there is at least one real not hit by any natural (which one obviously depends on the map).

Comment: I mean as I said that he does not compare against a fixed number such like $pi$ but against a formula which is changing in the process (just as in my example).

Comment: No, no metamathematical issues.

Comment: But checking against any fixed number would obviously fail. There is no formula here which changes at any point. But obviously you need to let the number depend on the chosen map (ie, on the chosen possible enumeration).

Comment: The standard diagonalization argument takes for granted some results about the decimal representation of real numbers. There is no need to embed proofs of these results in the proof of Cantor's Theorem.

Comment: Cantor's Diagonal Trick, with all its candor, simplicity and depth, won't apparently stop to be, in the foreseeable future, a  source of honest, real doubts, cranking and trolling and more and more posts...

Comment: I am willing to take Nicolas' point that Cantor's function will point to a converging series. What I ask for is indirectly within the proof.

Answer (score 3):

Cantor's argument is roughly the following:
Let $s:\ \Bbb{N}\ \longrightarrow\ \Bbb{R}$ be a sequence of real numbers. We show that it is not surjective, and hence that $\Bbb{R}$ is not enumerable. Identify each real number $s(n)$ in the sequence with a decimal expansion $s(n):\ \Bbb{N}\ \longrightarrow\ \{0,\ldots,9\}$. Then for example the sequence
$$r:\ \Bbb{N}\ \longrightarrow\ \{0,\ldots,9\}:\ n\ \longmapsto\ 9-(s(n))(n),$$
where $(s(n))(n)$ is the $n$-th digit of the $n$-th real number in the sequence $s$. By construction $r$ differs from $s(n)$ in the $n$-th place for every $n\in\Bbb{N}$, so it is not in the sequence $s$. Hence the real numbers are not enumerable.

The point of the proof the 'messing-up-function'. Given any sequence $s$ of real numbers, it returns a real number $r$ not in the sequence. To be explicit, the messing-up-function used as an example is
$$m:\ \Bbb{N}^{\Bbb{N}^{\{0,\ldots,9\}}}\ \longrightarrow\ \Bbb{N}^{\{0,\ldots,9\}}:\ s\ \longmapsto\ (n\ \mapsto\ 9-(s(n))(n)).$$

Answer (score 1):

No

For your suggestion on the natural numbers to work, it would need to be something like:

- List all the natural numbers
- Call the largest $n$ (if such a thing is possible)
- Add $1$ to $n$ to make $n+1$
- Show $n+1$ is not in the list, since it is larger than any natural number in the list.

But this fails, because there is no largest natural number, and so no $n$ to add $1$ to. So there is an unlimited number of natural numbers.

Cantor's diagonal proof says list all the reals in any countably infinite list (if such a thing is possible) and then construct from the particular list a real number which is not in the list.  This leads to the conclusion that it is impossible to list the reals in a countably infinite list.

Comment: I’d rather say that Cantor’s diagonal proof exhibits a method for taking any countably infinite list of real numbers and producing a real number not in the list, thereby showing that $\Bbb R$ is not countable. Similarly, the OP’s argument (slightly generalized) exhibits a method for taking a finite list of natural numbers and producing a natural number not in the list, thereby showing that $\Bbb N$ is not finite. They really are similar, when the OP’s argument is phrased in a way that actually makes sense.

Comment: My point is much stronger than looking for a largest N. I show that in at least one enumeration process, i.e. the one where the natural numbers are used to enumerate themselves, a process of checking from 1 to n, does not identify my number a function of the n first numbers (in my example n+1).

Comment: @Mikael: Are you claiming that the first $n$ numbers are all the natural numbers? If so, the this shows your claim is wrong; if not, then you are not matching Cantor's diagonal proof.

Answer (score 1):

In the diagonal argument, a function $f$ from the set of sequences of real numbers to $\mathbb{R}$ is defined. We start from any sequence $S$ of real numebrs. Then it is shown that $f(S)$ is not an element in $S$. The formula is not "changing during the process"; the number we are searching for, $f(S)$, is well-defined if $S$ is given. Now we have shown that for any sequence $S$ of real numbers, there is a real number which is an element of $S$.

The $n+1$ in your proof is not a definition of a number you are searching.

Comment: There is absolutely no need to phrase it as a proof by contradiction: the proof simply exhibits a mechanism for taking any countably infinite list of real numbers and producing a real number not in the list.

Comment: Oh, you're absolutely right. I don't know what I was thinking...

Comment: It depends on what you mean. The proof that ”the number is not in the list” can only be achieved by considering the number given by an infinite number of decimals, i.e. by considering a so called “actual infinity”. The alternative is to use 2 contradictions in series, i) that real numbers are countable and ii) that if that is the case, any number such as Cantor’s, must be in the list, i.e. must have a finite number in the list.

Comment: @MikaelJensen Yes, clearly we need to consider an infinite number of digits. If all reals could be written with a finite number of digits, the set of reals would be countable.

Comment: @Kildetoft The difference is not between a finite or a infinite set, but instead the difference between considering a number n in an infinite set vs considering all numbers simultaneously in an infinite set.

Comment: Let me say at this point that I consider that Nicolas has answered my question by a simple comment above, and perhaps I should be content with that. I have noted that the site moderators are not happy with long discussions.

Answer (score 0):

Cantor's proof is way more general than just showing that $\mathbb R$ is uncountable. The diagonal argument actually shows that no set can have the same cardinality as its power set (i.e. the set of all its subsets).

Regarding the concrete case of the real numbers, already when you state that real numbers can be written using infinite decimal expansions, you are using that they are characterized via a convergent series. No need to keep repeating that.

As for your argument, I cannot see what you mean when you say "not among those numbers".

Comment: Cantor's **original** proof, which is the famous "diagonal argument" is the one referred to. Later on he continued and improved upon the proof and showed the general (and perhaps simpler) result that you mention.

Comment: Agerami's point is equivalent to Nicolas' above. I agreed to that and I am bound to agree to it once more (but the issue seems to have a life of its own).

Answer (score 0):

> Let me similarly check whether a number I define is among the natural numbers. The number is n+1 and it is clear that 1,2,3 …n are not among these numbers. This “proofs” that n+1 is not a natural number.

No, all you have proven is that there is a positive integer ($n+1$) that is not in the list  $1, 2, \ldots, n$.

Such a fact does make for a perfectly good proof that $1, 2, \ldots, 73$ is not a list of *all* of the positive integers. It is even a proof that no list of the form $1, 2, \ldots, n$ (where $n$ is a positive integer) can be a list of *all* of the positive integers.

If the set of positive integers were finite, it would be of the form $1, 2, \ldots, n$. So it can even be used as a proof that the set of all positive integers is infinite.

---

All of that *is* analogous to the proof you reference. The diagonal argument (constructively) proves that every list of real numbers is missing a real number.

Thus, we conclude that there does not exist a list of all real numbers.

Comment: I am addressing how he proves it. What I have shown (or tried to show) is that a stepwise infinite comparison process of numbers in a list may sometimes provide strange results, unless you have requirements on the test quantity given as a function of 1 to n, in my case n+1 and in Cantor’s his description of the expansions (which converges to a number).

Comment: ... but you've shown nothing strange. You don't even state a strange fact that you're claiming to be showing!

Comment: To repeat myself: I have proved - or pointed out - that the failure of an infinite stepwise comparison between a number of a list and a function of the first n numbers, does not automatically supply a proof that a number is missing in the list.

Comment: @Mikael: If "infinite stepwise comparison" means the observation that Cantor's number is different from the $m$-th entry in the list in the $m$-th decimal digit, then you've shown no such thing. All you've shown is that the integer $n+1$ is not on the list $1, 2, \ldots, n$. As an aside, it is true that that doesn't *automatically* supply a proof: you additionally need to know that decimal numbers are actually real numbers, and that said real number has only one decimal expansion. (1, for example, has two decimal expansions: $1.\overline{0}$ and $0.\overline{9}$)

Comment: Nobody mentions that you have to know (right-infinite) decimals are (notations for) real numbers, because everybody already knows that. (and there are other ways around the non-unique decimal expansion issue, but ensuring that the diagonal number is one with a unique expansion is the usual method I see used)